# Animating menu with click on same button

Tags: jquery, css, menu, jquery-animate, toggle

So I have a button that I want to use to show/hide my menu div. I thought about toggle but since it targets the display of the div, it would end up hiding the button that toggles the menu. And I don't want to move the button.

The animation works fine on the click, but I haven't found a way to toggle it up and down. I tried adding .stop() commands but that just kills the whole thing... This is my code so far:

```
$('.closebutton').click(function () {
        $('#settings').stop().animate({top: '-170px'});
});

$('.closebutton').click(function() {
        $('#settings').stop().animate({top: '0px'});
});
```

The HTML:

```
 <div id="settings">
      <div class="closebutton"></div>
 </div>
```

And here we have the CSS:

```
 #settings {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #202e3c;
z-index: 9999;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
 }

 .closebutton {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
bottom: 5px;
right: 5px;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background: url(../images/gear.png);
background-size: cover;
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the applicable parts of your HTML?

Comment: Your HTML is really indispensable to answer this question. Looks like you have your nice button inside your `#settings`.

Comment: you want to completely hide the `#settings` panel? or to make it a bit visible like it is right now?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm just looking to move the panel up a bit, the `.closebutton` rests at the bottom right, so when the panel slides up I want it to be visible so you can click the button again to bring it back down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/igaqul/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
var t = 0; // Toggler

$('.closebutton').click(function ( e ) {

  t = ++t % 2;  // t= 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0......
  $('#settings').stop().animate({ top: t? -200 : 0 }); // #settings
  $(e.target).stop().animate({ bottom: t? -30 : 5  }); // This button

});
```

Without the stupid toggler:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/igaqul/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.closebutton').click(function ( e ) {

  var p = !$('#settings').position().top; // 0 = false else true (boolean trick)
  $('#settings').stop().animate({ top: p? -200 : 0 });
  $(e.target).stop().animate({ bottom: p? -30 : 5  });

});
```